# Discrete analogies of differentiable complex mappings?

Tags: complex-analysis, discrete-mathematics

For real differentiability, we can talk about [the finite difference operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) (see relation w/ derivative section). So, I am thinking similarish analogy be shown for complex differentiability? What could be some interesting results to come of such?

By analogy, I mean some sort of difference operation which under a limiting circumstance turns into the complex derivative. I suppose this would mean we would have some pair of equations which turn to Cauchy Riemann the limiting case.